# Is there a way to map data at multiple levels of a Swift Map?

Tags: swift

I'm wondering if there is a way to get data at multiple levels of a JSON object that I've got mapped in models?

Where `$0.product` is, there is also an array named `[Promotions]`. So ideally I'd like to be able to pull out into  `$0.promotion` as well as `$0.product` and have them insert into the same object (`testData`).

```
 self.holdTestData = testArray
    .compactMap { $0.search }
    .compactMap { $0.data }
    .flatMap { $0.results }
    .compactMap { $0.productItems }
    .compactMap { $0.product }
    .map {
        testData(
            name: $0.title,
            id: $0.id,
            weight: nil,
            Logo: "logo",
            price: nil,
            doublePrice: $0.price,
            imageURL: $0.defaultImageURL,
            barcode: ""
        )
    }
```

The names above aren't the actual names of my objects in the project, just because the  project is private. I'll try my best to show you what testArray derives from:-

```
  var testArray: [TestSearch]?

struct TestSearch: Codable {
    let search: Search
}


struct Search: Codable {
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let query: String
    let results: Results
 
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let productItems: [ProductItem]
}

struct ProductItem: Codable {
    let promotions: [Promotion]
    let product: TestProduct
}

struct Promotion: Codable {
    let promotionID, promotionType, startDate, endDate: String
    let offerText: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case promotionID = "promotionId"
        case promotionType, startDate, endDate, offerText
    }
}
```

Let me know if you also need me to include Product struct

**RESOLUTION:**

I had to go up a level, and then map from there:-

```
self.holdTestData = testArray.compactMap{
                                           $0.search
                                       }.compactMap{
                                           $0.data
                                       }.compactMap{
                                           $0.results
                                       }.flatMap{
                                           $0.productItems
                                       }.compactMap{
                                        testData(name: $0.product.title, id: $0.product.id, weight: nil, Logo: "logo", price: nil, doublePrice: $0.product.price, imageURL: $0.product.defaultImageURL, barcode: "", offerText: $0.promotions.isEmpty ? "" : $0.promotions[0].offerText)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? I also improved the formatting of your question, hope you don't mind

Comment: Could you give your objects structures, and what holds `testArray`? That could be much faster.

Comment: Edited as requested, apologies for the lack of information

Comment: `testArray.map({ $0.search.data.results.productItems })` should be one good step. You should have a `let items = [ProductItem]`, now, it's unclear what's `testData` link with `product` & `promotion`.

Comment: @Larme The example code I've given, works well for all of the information held within 'Product' and maps them well, I just couldn't retrieve 'offerText' out of Promotion for example to have it in the same object

Comment: Forget about the rest. What would you want to do if you have `let items = [ProductItem]`. I don't understand how you want to link `promotions` which is an array, with `product` and `offerText` and `testData`. How do you want to create your `testData` object? What properties does it needs, from which struct?

Comment: @Larme You gave me the right idea, I've managed to solve it from your suggestion. I've edited the above post to show. It seems there's an array of Promotions per Product, but it only ever contains a singular promotion. The array shows for every product, but may sometimes be empty

Comment: Still, if your sample is correct, there is no need to use `compactMap()`, `flatMap()` etc so many times. Just write: `testArray.map{ $0.search.data.results.productItems }.map{ testData(...) }`